# Display horizontal scrollbar in table

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, html-table

Refer to image as below, how can I display horizontal scrollbar in my table?

[image]

Below is the code, please look at the `<div>` style and `<table>` style.

```
@<div style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden">
            @<table class="table col-md-12 table-bordered" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="bg-danger">
                        <th style="text-align:center" class="col-md-1"> CODE </th>
                        <th style="text-align: center" class="col-md-2"> EVALUATION FACTOR </th>
                        @For Each item In Model.List_EvlRating.OrderByDescending(Function(m) m.N_Evl_Score)
                        @<th style="text-align: center">
                            @Html.Raw(item.Evl_Rating)
                        </th>
                        Next
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide us the HTML,CSS etc.

Comment: You can embed images instead of just linking them, and try to avoid personal phrases like "thanks guys".

Answer (score 0):

I think you were using third party grid and might be missing some configuration so its probably happen.

So if you are using any third party grid then i suggest to refer document for same.